# What's the difference: using namespae xxx outside namespace yyy and inside it?

Tags: c++, namespaces

```
namespace xxx {
using namespace yyy::zzz;
...
```

vs

```
using namespace yyy::zzz;
namespace xxx {
...
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The first one pull in all symbols from `yyy::zzz` into the `xxx` namespace.

The second first pulls in all symbols from `yyy::zzz` into the *global* namespace.